# Can WD3200AZRX SATA-3 hard drive work on SATA-2?

Tags: hard-drive, upgrade, sata, compatibility

I am buying new hard drive today, but I am worried that it will not work on my motherboard [**Gigabyte GA-945PL-S3**](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2325#ov).

I want to buy this  [**hard drive**](http://www.dateks.lv/en/cenas/23/63771_western_digital_320gb_5400_7200rpm_64mb_sata_iii_caviar_green.php). It's pretty expensive and I don't want to get disappointed. I can't find any documentation about the jumper settings and that's why I am asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will work, the main difference between SATA-2 AND SATA-3 is the theoretical throughput that each can achieve (SATA-2 3GB/S, SATA 3 6GB/S).

To quote the wiki page on SATA:

> The later standard is backwards compatible with SATA 3 Gbit/s

See the wiki page for more information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_revision_3.0_.28SATA_6_Gbit.2Fs.29

Answer (score 2):

Yes, any version of SATA is compatible with every version of SATA

Comment: But some people experience non-compatibility with newer hard drives on older motherboards, chipsets, etc..

Comment: @Roberts due to the SATA type or the HDD size? Older montherboards dont support HDD's above 2TB, but thats the only issue I've heard of. Guess you should wait for an answer from someone more experienced if you have heard of SATA incompatibility happening

Comment: Akash is right, compatability issues would more than likely occur because the motherboard doesn't support the size of the drive rather than the sata type being used.

Comment: @Dean and how can I tell that motherboard doesn't support this disk?

Comment: @Roberts I imagine it would be in the user documentation on the manufacturer's website, that would be where i would look. But as the disk is only 320gb i can't see it being an issue.. see Akash's comment  above.